# No enum constant Facebook EventBinding.MappingMethod.BUTTON_INDEXING

Tags: android, facebook, dependency-management

Is anyone receiving this runtime exception?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.facebook.appevents.codeless.internal.EventBinding.MappingMethod.BUTTON_INDEXING
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:257)
    at com.facebook.appevents.codeless.internal.EventBinding$MappingMethod.valueOf(EventBinding.java:154)
    at com.facebook.appevents.codeless.internal.EventBinding.getInstanceFromJson(EventBinding.java:82)
    at com.facebook.appevents.codeless.internal.EventBinding.parseArray(EventBinding.java:69)
    at com.facebook.appevents.codeless.CodelessMatcher$ViewMatcher.run(CodelessMatcher.java:224)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

We are using `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'`
I've tried the newest version `4.39.0`, but it also doesn't work. For some reason `4.33.0`, however, does work. The issue started at around 8pm UTC